# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:454 async execute(command)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have recently installed selenium-webdriver javascript(node) client 3.6.0

steps are follows;

```
# npm install webdriver
# npm install selenium-webdriver
# npm install chromedriver
```

install them into my project folder

then make a js file into that name "library.js"

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
By = webdriver.By;
until = webdriver.until;


driver.get('http://www.google.co.in');
```

[image]

This is showing async execute(command) error at require('selenium-webdriver')

node version V7.1.0.
npm version 3.10.9
chrome Version -  ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)

Help my in this how to run this

Comment: You have comma after `webdriver.By`.

Comment: `www.google.co.in` is not a valid url. The scheme is missing.

Comment: first typing node at console , then at node console writhing var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'); giving error.  Remove 'Comma' and add semicolon but still same

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue. Run `node -v` if your version is under 8 it doesn't have the ability to handle the `async` command. You'll have to update Node.

Answer (score 5):

The same issue, fix by upgrade Node to v8.9.4 as Faraji said above.